# can someone explain me why the #include directive in C allows to include files other that ".h" files

Tags: c, include, header-files, directive

can someone explain to me why writing something like:

```
#include "file.txt"       
#include "File.js"        /* why including files other than files with .h extension is valid */
#include "anotherFile.c"
main()
{

    printf("why including files other than header files (.h files) is allowed in C");

}
```

So can someone provide me a good tutorial online describing this. when i search online about this i find nothing. is this behavior of `#include directive` described somewhere in the [C standard pdf](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or [C standard html](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html) if so please guide me to the actual page where this behavior is described in the `C standard` with a link

Comment: `#include` is essentially just "paste the indicated file contents into this location right here". It's up to you as the coder to use it correctly.

Comment: The C standard does not say it has to be a header file: "A #include preprocessing
directive causes the named header or source file to be processed from phase 1
through phase 4, recursively"

Comment: A file extension is just a reminder for humans about the file contents. The real contents is what matters to the compiler. `echo "extern int foobar;" >foo.exe` and `#include "foo.exe"` is fine as far as the compiler (the preprocessor) is concerned

Comment: Because the C and C++ standards pose little constrains on what tokens can be used inside `< >` and `" "`.

Comment: @kaylum thank you. So now can you explain me what does it mean by `source file` does that mean `any file` can be included with the `#include directive`

Comment: @EricPostpischil That dup wasn't mine. It's a quirk of SO. I voted to close as "seeking recommendation" because question is asking for a tutorial. But the close reason only shows the majority votes.

Comment: @TonyTannous: The marked original was not a good candidate for this question. Although it is tagged C++ and C, it had only a C++ answer, and this question specifically asks for citations from the C standard. To fix that, I added a C answer there, but please respect submitters’ requests for specific information that is not present in other questions and their answers.

Comment: @alk: The marked original was not a good candidate for this question. Although it is tagged C++ and C, it had only a C++ answer, and this question specifically asks for citations from the C standard. To fix that, I added a C answer there, but please respect submitters’ requests for specific information that is not present in other questions and their answers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil my answer does cite the C standard. And addresses which characters are not permitted inside `<>` and inside `" "`

Comment: @TonyTannous: Yes, I see it alleges it cites ISO/IEC 9899:1999, but the text it shows for that says “5.8 Header names [lex.header]”, which is from a C++ standard, not a C standard. Also, the preference in Stack Overflow is to use the current standard, not a decades-old version (even if there are no changes in the issue at hand).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The include directive is part of the C Preprocessor. The preprocessor will simply replace an include with the contents of the file referenced.
See 6.10.2 Source file inclusion:

> A preprocessing directive of the form
> `#include "q-char-sequence" new-line` causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the source file identified by the
> specified sequence between the " delimiters.